# What is the process to install flutter desktop app

Tags: flutter

How to install flutter desktop app in windows and want to know the process of install and run hello world program for flutter desktop version.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The following might help you to re-write your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to provide at least some code or workings for people to help.

Comment: Are you asking how to set up your machine to develop desktop applications with Flutter, or how to build a Windows installer to distribute a desktop application built with Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

refer this blog it contains all details about how to create Desktop app 
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-for-desktop-create-and-run-a-desktop-application-ebeb1604f1e0

Comment: That post is five months old, and has outdated information. The official instructions, which are continuously updated, are at https://http://flutter.dev/desktop

Answer (score 0):

It is a longer process if you are a beginner. You will probably prefer running it in Chrome, an emulator or any external device.

Here are the commands to use in your terminal :

On macOS or Linux: `export ENABLE_FLUTTER_DESKTOP=true`

On Windows:

- PowerShell: `$env:ENABLE_FLUTTER_DESKTOP="true"`
- CMD: `set ENABLE_FLUTTER_DESKTOP=true`

Finally, run the following command to ensure that your system shows up.

```
flutter devices
set ENABLE_FLUTTER_DESKTOP=true
```